# Possible to change url target in lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction, lightning-datatable

I am using a `<lightning:datatable>` to display some data in a `Quick Action`. It works great, and I was able to get the table to display the name of a parent record as a link using a column definition looking like:

```
columns = [{
    label: "Parent",
    fieldName: "ParentLink",
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: {
        label: {
            fieldName: ParentName
        }
    }
}, {
    ...
}]
```

And in my callback for the server function which retrieves the record, I have some code looking like:

```
const records = response.getReturnValue();
records.forEach(function (record) {
    record.ParentLink = "/" + record.ParentId,
    record.ParentName = record.Parent.Name
});
```

Functionally, this approach does everything we need, but the user experience is not optimal. The anchor tag which gets rendered on the page looks like:

```
<a href="/parentId" title="/parentId" target="_blank">ParentName</a>
```

Is there any way I can control the `title` and `target` attributes? The latter is the major problem, because opening the record in a new tab is antithetical to the navigation paradigm in Lightning Experience. Given that it is a `Quick Action` modal, I would prefer it to be `target="_top"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typeAttributes` for a `url` field accepts an additional parameter, `target`, which carries through to the generated `<a>` tag.

It's [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) in the Lightning Component Library, but only in passing:

> ```
> TYPE  DESCRIPTION                                 SUPPORTED TYPE ATTRIBUTES
> url   Displays a URL using lightning:formattedUrl label, target, tooltip
> ```

I've applied it successfully with, e.g.,

```
typeAttributes: { 
    label: {
        fieldName: 'CaseNumber'
    },
    target: '_self'
},
```

in the past, which works well for in-page links in Console applications.

Similarly, `tooltip` maps to `title`.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I've had a hard time finding good documentation on `columns` in general, and mostly relied on examples instead.

Comment: The `tooltip` attribute does indeed control `title`, and works the same way as `label` in that you can specify `fieldName`. Thanks for the quick response! I'm using `target: "_top"`, but that's the only difference.

Comment: It's odd that `target` => `target` but `tooltip` => `title`. I've never used that one before so tried it in a demo project.